# What is the point of copying a slice?

Tags: go

What is the point of this snippet of code:

```
t := make([]byte, len(s), (cap(s)+1)*2) // +1 in case cap(s) == 0
for i := range s {
    t[i] = s[i]
}
s = t
```

It's from this page: http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals, and is supposed to grow a slice. However, above that code snippet is a diagram which depicts a slice as a struct with a pointer, a length, and a capacity. Why does each individual entry have to be copied over instead of something like:

```
t := make([]byte, len(s), (cap(s)+1)*2) // +1 in case cap(s) == 0
t = s[:]
s = t
```

And if the problem is that the capacity of `t` is changed to be the same as `s`, why isn't there another way of setting the pointers to be the same. Or does a slice have a pointer to every single element in the array within its bounds?

Edit: I read a little further and got to this snippet of code:

```
func CopyDigits(filename string) []byte {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    b = digitRegexp.Find(b)
    c := make([]byte, len(b))
    copy(c, b)
    return c
}
```

Its purpose is to stop referencing the file after `c` is returned by using `copy`. Does this imply that `copy` copies the underlying array as well as the slice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To construct a new, higher capacity underlying array with the same length and values as the old underlying array. The old underlying array will be reclaimed by the garbage collector. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}[:3]
    fmt.Printf("s: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &s[0], len(s), s, cap(s), s[:cap(s)])
    t := make([]byte, len(s), (cap(s)+1)*2) // +1 in case cap(s) == 0
    fmt.Printf("t: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &t[0], len(t), t, cap(t), t[:cap(t)])
    for i := range s {
        t[i] = s[i]
    }
    s = t
    fmt.Printf("s: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &s[0], len(s), s, cap(s), s[:cap(s)])
    fmt.Printf("t: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &t[0], len(t), t, cap(t), t[:cap(t)])
}
```

Output:

```
s: 0x10500168 3 [0 1 2] 5 [0 1 2 3 4]
t: 0x1052e130 3 [0 0 0] 12 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
s: 0x1052e130 3 [0 1 2] 12 [0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
t: 0x1052e130 3 [0 1 2] 12 [0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The function copy copies slice elements from a source src to a
>   destination dst and returns the number of elements copied. Both
>   arguments must have identical element type T and must be assignable to
>   a slice of type []T. The number of elements copied is the minimum of
>   len(src) and len(dst).
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> var a = [...]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
> var s = make([]int, 6)
> var b = make([]byte, 5)
> n1 := copy(s, a[0:])            // n1 == 6, s == []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> n2 := copy(s, s[2:])            // n2 == 4, s == []int{2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5}
> n3 := copy(b, "Hello, World!")  // n3 == 5, b == []byte("Hello")
> ```

If we return a reference to `b`, we pin the whole underlying array for `b`. Since `b` refers to a file, that could easily be megabytes or gigabytes. By returning a new underlying array `c`, which is the exact size of the number, a few bytes, there will no longer be a reference to the large underlying array for `b` and it will be reclaimed by the garbage collector. The `copy` built-in function copies values from `b` to `c`. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func Copy() []byte {
    b := []byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
    fmt.Printf("b: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &b[0], len(b), b, cap(b), b[:cap(b)])
    b = b[:2]
    fmt.Printf("b: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &b[0], len(b), b, cap(b), b[:cap(b)])
    c := make([]byte, len(b))
    copy(c, b)
    fmt.Printf("c: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &c[0], len(c), c, cap(c), c[:cap(c)])
    return c
}

func main() {
    d := Copy()
    fmt.Printf("d: %p %d %v %d %v\n", &d[0], len(d), d, cap(d), d[:cap(d)])
}
```

Output:

```
b: 0x10500168 8 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7] 8 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
b: 0x10500168 2 [0 1] 8 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
c: 0x10500178 2 [0 1] 2 [0 1]
d: 0x10500178 2 [0 1] 2 [0 1]
```